# How to Highlight Cells with particular values in a GridView in ASP .NET using VB Programming?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, asp-classic

I have a Databound-GridView on an ASP .NET Web Page. I am using VB as the programming language. I want to Highlight the Cells with value greater than 10 in Red. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely what you are looking for... though you'll need to customize things to fit the exact criteria of your program. I don't imagine all your fields are integers so the `CInt` will likely throw an exception. I can give you a more specific approach if I knew what the layout of your gridview was.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim max As Integer = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To max

            Dim nbr As String = e.Row.Cells(i).Text.ToString 

            If Not Integer.TryParse(nbr, nbr) Then

                nbr = "0"

            End If

            If CInt(nbr) > 10 Then

                e.Row.Cells(i).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention. One of the columns has Text Values in it. It is generating the error "Conversion from string "XYZ" to type 'Integer' is not valid. How can I over-ride this?

Comment: Updated answer with a possible workaround for fields containing strings/text.